# Playa field explodes Matrix field

Tags: matrix, playa, pixelandtonic, ee1

I have an issue with an old build.

EE 1.6.8 - Build 20090723
Matrix 2.0.11
Playa 3.1.2

I create the matrix field fine, but if I add a playa segment, after saving the field, I can no longer access the field. If I click on the field label to edit it, I am shown nothing but an Update button. I can not edit the field in the entry template either. I need to get this fixed until I get everything rebuilt and updated to 2.

Comment: Hi Brian, can you please contact us at support@pixelandtonic.com, and include your Matrix and Playa license keys? We can get you hooked up with a more recent version of Matrix, which might solve your issue.

Comment: @BrandonKelly - Sent the email. I didn't know what I could update to (Version wise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Brandon on this via email and we updated everything to the newest versions. This still did not resolve the issues. I was able to correct the issues I was having by reverting all the way back to the older FF Matrix fieldtype. This is the same solution I had to apply to another issue I was having which leads me to believe this issue is due to the way this old site was built and maintained.

I am in the process of a complete rebuild and will be moving it all into EE2 so this should "disappear". I will set this as answered, if nothing else to remove it from the radar of unanswered questions.